# Rename table using migration in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, migration

I am running a migration to rename a table but I get an odd error.

```
public function up()
{   
    Schema::rename($accounts, $feeds);
}   

public function down()
{   
    Schema::rename($feeds, $accounts);
}
```

**Error**:

`Undefined variable: accounts`

Table definitely exists. Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use string and not variable:

```
public function up()
{   
    Schema::rename('accounts', 'feeds');
}   

public function down()
{   
    Schema::rename('feeds', 'accounts');
}
```